# Iterators for a tree structure using QCell

Tags: rust

I wanted to try out one of the compile time checked RefCell types (`LCell` from the qcell crate) to build a simple tree data structure with an iterator. However, I get confused about the lifetimes of the iterator as `LCellOwner` also takes a "lifetime" as a way to declare ownership about the cells. How do I get this to compile?

```
use qcell::{LCell, LCellOwner};

pub enum Node<'id, T> {
    Folder(Vec<LCell<'id, Node<'id, T>>>),
    Data(T),
}

pub struct Tree<'id, T> {
    root: LCell<'id, Node<'id, T>>,
}

impl<'id, T> Tree<'id, T> {
    pub fn new(data: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            root: LCell::new(Node::Folder(vec![LCell::new(Node::Data(data))])),
        }
    }

    pub fn iter(&self, token: &LCellOwner<'id>) -> Iter<T> {
        Iter {
            stack: vec![&self.root],
            token,
        }
    }
}

pub struct Iter<'id, 'a, T> {
    stack: Vec<&'a LCell<'id, Node<'id, T>>>,
    token: &'a LCellOwner<'id>,
}

impl<'id, 'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'id, 'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a Node<'id, T>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let next_node = self.stack.pop()?.ro(self.token);

        if let Node::Folder(children) = next_node {
            for child in children.iter().rev() {
                self.stack.push(child);
            }
        }

        Some(next_node)
    }
}
```

Current compiler error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src\tree.rs:22:9
   |
14 |   impl<'id, T> Tree<'id, T> {
   |        --- lifetime `'id` defined here
...
21 |       pub fn iter(&self, token: &LCellOwner<'id>) -> Iter<T> {
   |                   - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
22 | /         Iter {
23 | |             stack: vec![&self.root],
24 | |             token,
25 | |         }
   | |_________^ associated function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'id` but it is returning data with lifetime `'1`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of the type `tree::Iter<'_, '_, T>`, which makes the generic argument `'_` invariant
   = note: the struct `tree::Iter<'id, 'a, T>` is invariant over the parameter `'id`
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you can go through a few simple steps:

1. Explicitly name all the lifetimes:

   ```rust
   pub fn iter<'this, 'token, 'iter>(
       &'this self,
       token: &'token LCellOwner<'id>
   ) -> Iter<'id, 'iter, T> {
   ```

   Your good names let me infer `'id` is supposed to be the first lifetime of `Iter` rather than introducing a 4th lifetime

   This let's the compiler help us with very useful hints like these:

   ```
   [...]
   error: lifetime may not live long enough
     --> src/lib.rs:24:9
      |
   20 |       pub fn iter<'this, 'token, 'iter>(
      |                          ------  ----- lifetime `'iter` defined here
      |                          |
      |                          lifetime `'token` defined here
   ...
   24 | /         Iter {
   25 | |             stack: vec![&self.root],
   26 | |             token,
   27 | |         }
      | |_________^ method was supposed to return data with lifetime `'iter` but it is returning data with li
   fetime `'token`
      |
      = help: consider adding the following bound: `'token: 'iter`
      = note: requirement occurs because of the type `Iter<'_, '_, T>`, which makes the generic argument `'_`
    invariant
      = note: the struct `Iter<'id, 'a, T>` is invariant over the parameter `'id`
      = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance

   help: the following changes may resolve your lifetime errors
     |
     = help: add bound `'this: 'iter`
     = help: add bound `'token: 'iter`
   ```
2. Apply the tips the compiler gives us:

   ```rust
   pub fn iter<'this: 'iter, 'token: 'iter, 'iter>(
       &'this self,
       token: &'token LCellOwner<'id>,
   ) -> Iter<'id, 'iter, T> {
   ```

   The code now compiles.
3. (Optional) Simplify the lifetimes. Since all references we work with are shared the lifetimes here are all variant, wich means the compiler can easily shorten them to fit our bill, so actually we can just use the same lifetime for both our arguments and the iterator:

   ```rust
   pub fn iter<'a>(&'a self, token: &'a LCellOwner<'id>) -> Iter<'id, 'a, T> {
   ```

---